# passing data from button in cell to another tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, segue

how do I pass data from button in menu tableview to cart tableview?
would I segue it, use closures, protocol/delegates, something else?

Im having trouble passing data from my AddtoCart Button in my MenuViewController to CartViewController

the objective is to put items in the CartVC when the ATC button is pressed in the MenuCell

The CartButton on the NavBar in the MenuVC segues to the CartVC when pressed

The ATC button in the cell passes all the selected cells data to the cartVC (image, name, category, weight & price)

Im using Cloud Firestore to post data to populate my VC cells

I have tried so many different solutions posted on stack and still nothing seems to works, I have been stuck on this for almost 2 weeks... any help would be much much appreciated

[image: TBV2TBV]

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import Firebase


class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var items: Items!

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var weight: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCart: RoundButton!

    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        name.text = items.name
        category.text = items.category
        image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.image))
        price.text = items.price
        weight.text = items.weight
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cartButton: BarButtonItem!!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var itemSetup: [Items] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell") as? MenuCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.configure(withItem: itemSetup[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Cart.currentCart.cartItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell

        let cart = Cart.currentCart.CartItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblWeight.text = cart.items.weight         
        cell.lblMealName.text = "\(cart.items.category): \(cart.items.name)"
        cell.lblSubTotal.text = "$\(cart.items.price)"  
        cell.imageUrl                                // can't figure out how to pass image

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class CartItem {

    var items: Items

    init(items: Items) {
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that runs when the user taps the add to cart button, but it should add the item to the cart.  The show cart VC should simply show the cart.  There should be no need for the add to cart button to communicate directly with the show cart VC.

Comment: ***@Paulw11***, you're right I removed the code that previously attempted using since it wasn't working at passing the data from the ATC btn in the MenuVC cells to the CartVC. since most the things I attempted were not working or just didn't push the data to the data to the CartVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is get rid of `CartItem` - It doesn't seem to be doing anything except wrapping an `Items` instance, and you have some confusion in your code as to whether you are using `CartItem` or `Items` (I would probably also rename `Items` to `Item` - singular).

```
class Cart {
    static let currentCart = Cart()
    var cartItems = [Items]()
}
```

To get the "add to cart" action from your cell you can use a delegation pattern or provide a closure to handle the action.  I will use a closure

```
class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var weight: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCart: RoundButton!

    var addActionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        name.text = items.name
        category.text = items.category
        image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.image))
        price.text = items.price
        weight.text = items.weight
    }

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.addActionHandler?()
    }

}
```

Now, in your menu `cellForRowAt` you can provide the action handler:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell") as! MenuCell // Just crash at this point if there isn't a valid cell identifier configured
    let item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(withItem: item)
    cell.addActionHandler = {
        Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
    }
    return cell
}
```

And that should be all you need to do - When you segue to the cart view controller, it will show the current contents of the cart.

Note that you could improve your cart data model somewhat by allowing it to have a quantity for each item and providing an `add(item:)` function that incremented the quantity if the item was in the cart

Comment: ill work on this as soon as im out of class sorry if it takes some for you to get a reponse